# How to create relationships with the friendlist module in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

All I want is a simple link that a user can click on, to create a request to become another user's friend. The documentation is very vague on this. Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Decided to use API function directly:

```
friendlist_api_relation_add($requester, $requestee, $rtid, $message, $user_generated = TRUE)
```